# { "errors": [ { "detail": "The caller does not have permission" } ] }

Tags: python, google-sheets

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

GENDER = YOUR GENDER
WEIGHT_KG = YOUR WEIGHT
HEIGHT_CM = YOUR HEIGHT
AGE = YOUR AGE

APP_ID = YOUR NUTRITIONIX APP ID
API_KEY = YOUR NUTRITIONIX API KEY

exercise_endpoint = "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise"
sheet_endpoint = YOUR SHEETY ENDPOINT

exercise_text = input("Tell me which exercises you did: ")

headers = {
    "x-app-id": APP_ID,
    "x-app-key": API_KEY,
}

parameters = {
    "query": exercise_text,
    "gender": GENDER,
    "weight_kg": WEIGHT_KG,
    "height_cm": HEIGHT_CM,
    "age": AGE
}

response = requests.post(exercise_endpoint, json=parameters, headers=headers)
result = response.json()

################### Start of Step 4 Solution ######################

today_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
now_time = datetime.now().strftime("%X")

for exercise in result["exercises"]:
    sheet_inputs = {
        "workout": {
            "date": today_date,
            "time": now_time,
            "exercise": exercise["name"].title(),
            "duration": exercise["duration_min"],
            "calories": exercise["nf_calories"]
        }
    }

    sheet_response = requests.post(sheet_endpoint, json=sheet_inputs)

    print(sheet_response.text)
```

I expected to happen, a new row of data in My Google Sheet

but instead,happened this,

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "detail": "The caller does not have permission"
    }
  ]
}
```

The error is this:

> raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)    requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url:

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
You are directly opening the sheet link provided by Angela, so you are just a viewer in this sheet and  using it in sheety api.
instead, make a copy(the googleSheet>File>Make a Copy) and then use this copy in sheety api and your code.

Answer (score 0):

you just need have a copy of googlesheet and take its api.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).